# Apache2 not starting

Tags: linux, apache, apache2

Every time I try to start apache, I get this:

```
#: /etc/apache2 apache2ctl restart 
httpd not running, trying to start
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I've scanned port 80 with:

```
nmap -sU -p 80 [hostname]
```

and

```
nmap -p 80 [hostname]
```

and it said nothing was running on those ports. I have no clue what's going on, the only thing I've done recently is edit some of my vhost .conf files. And the error.log file shows nothing recent. Any help?

Comment: Are you out of disk space? Have you tried to listen to a different port such as 8080? What do your configuration files look like?

Comment: Not out of disk space. Different port failed, same message. I'll post some .conf files above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, I fixed it by completely reinstalling by following the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26228/how-can-i-reinstall-apache-httpd-after-deleting-some-of-the-configuration-files), aka:

```
aptitude purge apache2.2-common apache2
aptitude install apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache error log, it will show what may be the problem.  It could be multiple parts of apache trying for 80, etc. The log file is the first thing to check.

A good idea to check if the port was already running some other port 80 service.

Comment: If you're talking about /var/log/apache2/error.log, it hasn't shown a new message for 2 hours. I'm positive nothing's running on 80, plus the problem continues even if I switch to 8080.

Comment: There should be a start up errors - yes.   Also /var/log/messages could have some helpful information etc.  I assume you just tried a plain stop and then a start rather than restart. Lots of interesting causes, though '/conf/extras folder ' includes as well that can cause an issue.  Odd your not getting any messages.   Your trying to start as root ?

Comment: Tried stop/starting it as well as restarting it, no dice. I'm starting as root, yes, although the problem continues when I try to sudo ... it as well.